# Accessing usb iso image using virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

I am using mac Yosemite 10.0.1 and i want to run ubuntu using virtualbox. I have the iso image on a usb drive but the usb is not recognised by virtual box. I can see it but it is disabled. Any suggestions?

Comment: have you tried to copy the iso file to your local harddisk?

Answer (score 0):

Well you have to mount the iso file on the USB using image mounting software like powerIso.

check this out : http://www.justwebworld.com/create-bootable-usb-drive-using-power/